# MSTest Unit Testing Controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, mstest

**Learning MSTest** -- trying to unit test a REST function:  *AccountController* (which I believe will work) I want to start with *Register*.  I can't get the Mocks setup for some reason.  (Moq is installed).
Also, I'm confused as to how this could possibly be of any use; if I mock all the controller inputs, I'm not going to get anything back?  Your Advice?

AccountController - target of the unit test:

```
namespace API.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public AccountController(
            UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            ITokenService tokenService,
            IMapper mapper)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _tokenService = tokenService;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

    [HttpPost("register")]
    // [Authorize]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UserDto>> Register(RegisterDto registerDto)
    {
        if (await this.UserExistsAsync(registerDto.Username)) return BadRequest("Username is taken");

        var user = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(registerDto);
        user.UserName = registerDto.Username.ToLower();
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, registerDto.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded) return BadRequest(result.Errors);

        var roleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
        if (!roleResult.Succeeded) return BadRequest(result.Errors);

        return new UserDto
        {
            Username = user.UserName,
            Token = await _tokenService.CreateToken(user),
            KnownAs = user.KnownAs
        };
    }
```

BTW BaseController is simply:

```
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
    {      
    }
}
```

The Unit Test so far is:

```
namespace API.Controllers.Tests
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class AccountControllerTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public async void AccountController_Register()
        {
            var _userManager = new Mock<UserManager<AppUser>>();
            var _signInManager = new Mock<SignInManager<AppUser>>();
            var _roleManager = new Mock<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            ITokenService tokenService;
            IMapper mapper;

            RegisterDto userDto = new RegisterDto()
            {
                Username = "Admin",
                Password = "Secret1234",
                FirstName = "Johnny",
                LastName = "Appleseed",
                Phone1 = "6175551212",
                Phone2 = "",
                KnownAs = "Dude",
                EmailAddress = "Dude@Somewhere.com",
                Question = "ask",
                Answer = "answer",
            };

            AccountController accountController = new AccountController(_userManager, 
                                                    _signInManager, 
                                                    _roleManager, 
                                                    tokenService, 
                                                    mapper);
            await accountController.Register(userDto);

            Assert.Fail(); <<---- this will be replaced obviously
        }
```

The compiler error looks like this:
[image]

Other arguments have a similar error message.

Your Advice OR point me to a tutorial somewhere that covers MSTest Mocks :-)
Thanks in advance.

Chuck

Comment: Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get an idea of how to actually use the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Mock<T>` you need to call `.Object` to get the mocked  type

```
AccountController accountController = 
    new AccountController(_userManager.Object, //<-- NOTE ".Object" on Mock<T>
        _signInManager.Object, 
        _roleManager.Object, 
        tokenService, 
        mapper);
```

Also you will need to setup the expected behavior using `.Setup` so that the mock behave as expected when the subject under test is being exercised.

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get an idea of how to actually use the library

Comment: Thank you so much... studying the Quickstart now :-)